# Can't restore a backup of database which has TDE enabled

Tags: sql-server, restore, encryption, transparent-data-encryption

I'm trying to restore the backup of database which has Transparent Data Encryption enabled. I have verified the certificate thumbprint in the backup file is the same as TDE certificate in [master] database.

[image: TDEThumbprint]

TDE certificate:

[image]

**However the restoration is failing with the error:**

[image]

It is requesting the old certificate. Note that we changed TDE certificate some time ago and the database master key was encrypted with the new certificate using the alter database command:

```
USE [db];
GO
ALTER DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE [New_Certificate];
GO
```

The old certificate was still in [master] database when the backup was made and it was removed some time after.

This looks like a bug.

Any explanations, suggestions?

version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-OD) (KB5006943) - 13.0.6404.1 (X64)

**[EDIT1]:**

I restored the "old" certificate from backup and the database restore was successful. Checked the encryption status - database was protected with the "new" certificate as expected and I dropped the "old" certificate:
[image]

But then **the same error appears with database backup** - asking for the "old" certificate again:

[image]

**[EDIT2]:**

I decrypted the database and re-encrypted. The decryption was successful only on second attempt:

[image]

Comment: Hi! I edited the question and added more info.

Comment: It's not a bug. There are still log items protected by the old cert which is why you need it.

Comment: Why would SQL Server allow me to drop a certificate if it is still protecting some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem was caused by some transaction log records encrypted with the "old" and dropped certificate. I could not truncate the transaction log until I decrypted an re-encrypted the database. I assume this is a bug, because SQL Server should not allow to drop a certificate if still being used anywhere.

Comment: Still not a bug, no matter how much you want it to be. It's in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/error-after-perform-tde-certificate-key-rotation

Comment: Oh, nice, a bug is not considered a bug if you document it :D I would call it "known bug".

Comment: Calling something a bug because it doesn't work the way you want it to does not make it a bug. I would urge you to understand the actual working of the technology before calling things bugs, otherwise it shows your ignorance.

Comment: Yeah, let's call it a feature, not the bug, right? :D A feature, which could lead to lost database. But, of course, it would be DBA's fault, because - always backup your keys and keep them forever :)